# Android IAP Subscription - How to get original orderID while receiving realtime developer notifications

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement my own server for processing android's In-App Subscriptions validation.

I need to process google's Realtime Developer Notificaions, which are fired when users, for example, renews subscription.

Google sends to me purchase token, and I use that token to get order via AndroidPublisher api.

However, AndroidPublisher for renew purchase returns orderID field, which is not the same as in original purchase - renew purchase contains orderID with suffix `..1`.

How can I get orderID of the first purchase in a row of renews? Because I want to update user's purchases on my server.

Is it safe to just strip `\.\.\d+$` regexp from orderID?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use OrderID to identify user's purchase or subscription. User purchaseToken instead. More details here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#tokens